# date input from file and output conversion to file

Tags: php, text-files

I have a file of dates in format yyyy-mm-dd  eg 1988-12-27

I want to read from this file and out the corresponding dates in format eg. 27th December,1988 to another file.

this is the sample code that does the conversion: I'm left with the reading from file and outputing it to another file. Thanks

```
$input     = '1988-12-27';
$timestamp = strtotime($input);
$output    = date('dS F, Y', $timestamp);
echo $output;
```

Comment: File Write - http://www.tizag.com/phpT/filewrite.php and File Read - http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileread.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer here:

```
 <?php
$content = file_get_contents('origin.txt');
$dates = explode("\n", $content);
foreach($dates as $date) {
$timestamp = strtotime($date);
 $output    = date('dS F, Y', $timestamp);
$myFile = "output.txt";
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = $output."\n";
fwrite($fh, $stringData);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

And you're looking for a way to output your dates into another file?

Here you go: http://php.net/manual/de/function.file-put-contents.php

```
file_put_contents('file.txt', $output, FILE_APPEND);
```

Edit:
Reading works almost exactly:

i'm assuming that your origin file looks like this:

```
Date1
Date2
Date3
```

See my code:

```
$content = file_get_contents('origin.txt');
$dates = explode("\n", $content);
foreach($dates as $date) {
    // add your code here and write output to the new file
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_files.htm

You will need to use fopen() to  create file handles, fread() to read from the input, and fwrite() to write to the output